# Rails3 asset pipeline running partially

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have two applications with similar functionality for handling images.  The configuration is nearly identical including a sub-folder of images.  The first application concatenates, minifies, uglifies and manifests everything.

The second, while it creates a manifest file, with sub-folders minified and registered in the manifest, the compiled css file:

```
"/assets/application-4898960c10f155d9863996c1768de30a.css"
```

generated via

```
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require foundationextra.css
 *= require normalize
 *= require_self
 *= require prettyphoto-rails
```

remains **un-concatenated, un-minified** and **some of the images are not referencing the manifest** compiled files.  I suspect the files that are manifested are from the gem bundle
`shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/prettyphoto-rails-0.2.1/vendor/assets/images` 
  I fail to find any configuration issues that differ between the sites, aside from

```
*= require_tree .
```

which I need to avoid in the second application (browser-based css and js files are included).  But above all, if `/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/prettyphoto-rails-0.2.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets` is also part of the `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`, then why is that not concatenating, etc...

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is turns out to be quite useful.  If the compiled CSS file is not minified/uglified, then you've got a syntaxic CSS error someplace.

In this instance a colon in lieu of a semi-colon.

So running the compilation actually also runs a check on the code.